# Find the particular solution for the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following differential equation, find the particular solution:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t-ty}{1+t^2}$$
given: $y(1)=-7 $

I was wondering if someone could help me with the integration? This is how far I have gotten..

I tried to solve this using the separation of variables. 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t(1-y)}{1+t^2}$$ then I rewrote it as 
$$\int \frac{t}{1+t^2} dt=\int \frac{1}{1-y} dy $$
then I got $$\frac{1}{2} \ln(1+t^2)=-\ln(1-y)+c $$

I am a little shaky with natural logs so I was wondering if someone could finish it from here for me with a step by step explanation? Thank you!

Comment: Please use Latex. It is unclear about what sits in the denominator for example. It does not seem like a very difficult question but we want to be sure...

Comment: $\text{ if the equation was meant to be } \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t-ty}{1+t^2} \\ \text{ then I don't see anything wrong with your answer so far} \\ \text{ just need to apply the initial condition } \\ \text{ though I would write the answer as } \\ \frac{1}{2}ln|1+t^2|=-ln|1-y|+c$

Comment: @randomgirl Yes that is what it is. Can you show me how to finish the problem using separation of variables?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I know I finished integrating but I want to know if you can help me solve for y. I know I exponentiate both sides but I get a little confused with the natural log

Comment: right now I have (1+t^2)^1/2=1/1-y +c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but its better to use absolute value in logarithm arguments.
If you have trouble to eliminate logarithms,note that your solution can be written as:
$$
\ln\left(\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)=-\ln|1-y|+\ln K \qquad K>0
$$
and if you exponentiate
$$
\sqrt{1+t^2}=\dfrac{K}{1-y}
$$
$$
y=1-\dfrac{K}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}
$$
Since your inital condition is $y(1)=-7$ you can find $K=8\sqrt{2}$

---

added all steps from the first to the second equation:
$$
\ln\left(\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)=\ln\left(\dfrac{K}{|1-y|}\right) \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\exp\left(\ln \left(\sqrt{1+t^2} \right)\right)=\exp\left(\ln \left(\dfrac{K}{|1-y|}\right)\right) \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\sqrt{1+t^2}=\dfrac{K}{1-y}
$$

Comment: Can you explain how e^ln(1+t^2)^1/2=e^ln(1-y)^-1+c gives you (1+t^2)^1/2=k/1-y

Comment: $e^{\ln x} = x$

Comment: @lil: I've added all steps.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{ using the initial condition is what you mean } \\ \text{b/c you already done the separation of variables part ? } \\  y(1)=-7 \\ \text{ means you are going to replace } \\ t \text{ with } 1 \\ \text{ and } y \text{ with } -7  \text{ and solve for } C. \\ \text{ So you have } \\ \frac{1}{2} \ln|1+1^2|=- \ln|1-(-7)|+C \\ \frac{1}{2} \ln|2|=-\ln|8|+C \\ \text{ not too many steps to follow to find out our constant } \\ \text{ also emilio gave another way to look at the constant }$